# Smartface app rejected from app store because of lack of ipv6 support in soap service

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, smartface.io

I submitted my app to the app store after building it on Smartface Cloud9 and it was rejected because it can not communicate with the server on an ipv6 only network. I am not using any ipv4 literals in my code, only domain names. I have no idea what to do here and would love is someone else knew the solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: can you check your url's ipv6 validation from http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php ?

Comment: This problem is resolved by Smartface. When your workspace is updated, it is automatically fixed with new publish.